# How to convert nano second to seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time, timestamp

Is there a way to convert the event.timestamp to regular metrics. My current output is 267185117663619 (nanosecond??). Is there a way to conver this to, let's say miliseconds or even seconds?

```
  timestamp = String.valueOf(event.timestamp);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `1 s = 1,000 ms = 1,000,000 µs = 1,000,000,000 ns`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could just divide it by `1,000,000,000` .

This way:

```
double seconds = (double)Long.parseLong(timestamp)/1000000000.0;
```